# Stop script when item occurs in array

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array like this

```
array
  2 => string 'Member forum 1'
  5 => string 'Member forum 5'
  8 => string 'Moderator forum 8'
  9 => string 'Member forum 9'
```

I would like to write a script that, once it hits the `Moderator`-tag, stops looking for the tag and continue with a variable which contains `true` or something alike for which I can tell a user is a Moderator on any form of just a normal member.

I have been experimenting with `in_array` and `preg_match` but everytime I end up with a `false` result, cause the last item of the array (`Member forum 9`) overwrites the  `true` value of the last but one value (`Moderator forum 8`).

Here is my try. `$user_roles` being the array mentionned above.

```
$user_roles = $user->roles;

foreach($user_roles as $value) {
    if(preg_match('Moderator', $value)) {
        var_dump('yep, moderator');
        break;
    } elseif(preg_match('Redacteur', $value)) {
        var_dump('jep, redacteur');
        break;
    } else {
        var_dump('nope');
    }
}
```

Comment: Preg_match is overkill here, stripos should do, check my answer.

Comment: please see below you can use stripos instead of regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this?

```
$arr = array(...);
$found = false;
foreach($arr as $item)
{
    if( stripos($item, 'moderator') !== false)
    {
        $found = $item;
        break;
    }
}

if($found)
{
    //$found is the word.
}
```

If there could be more than 1 possible match and you have to process every match:

```
foreach($arr as $item)
{
    if( stripos($item, 'moderator') !== false)
    {
        $roles = explode(' ',trim($item));
        $role = trim(strtolower($roles[0]));
        switch($role)
        {
             case 'moderator': 
                  //do something
                  break;
             case 'moderator1':
                  //another thing
                  break;
             case ....
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, great! Thanks. But what if I too have a role called "moderator2"? How can I distinguish these two roles. Should I use a common `if('moderator2' == $found)`-function for this, or can I do this in the same function you gave before?

Comment: in that case, if possible match is more 1 we should not break, but if you assume that the first match will suffice break will make sense

Answer (score 1):

How about this? It's more versatile than the other answers, anyway:

```
<?php
$user_roles = array(
    2 => 'Member forum 1',
    5 => 'Member forum 5',
    8 => 'Moderator forum 8',
    9 => 'Member forum 9'
);


function contains( $string, array $roles ) {
    foreach( $roles as $key => $value ) {
        if( stripos( $value, $string ) !== false ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$moderator = contains( 'moderator', $user_roles );
$redacteur = contains( 'redacteur', $user_roles );

var_dump( $moderator, $redacteur ); // true, false.
```

*Addendum*: As for the reason your preg_match didn't work: it doesn't have any delimiters, but a regular expression always should. So the example should work:

```
<?php
$string = 'Moderator forum 8';
if( 0 !== preg_match( '~moderator~i', $string ) ) { // ~ is the delimiter.
    echo "Moderator found.";
}
```

I still agree with the other that stripos is more suited for this occasion, though.

Comment: Thanks for the great snippet. But the answer of jerjer was more applicable for my situation! Thanks again!

Comment: No worries, use what you can :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, `$arr` is your array:

```
$iFailSafe = 1;
$iNumValues= count($arr);
while($found == false)
    $value = current($arr);        
    if(stripos("moderator",$value) !== false){
      $found = true;
      $userId = key($arr);
    }
    if($iFailSafe == $iNumValues) $found = true;
    next($arr);
    $iFailSafe++;
}
```

Comment: this can be very dangerous cause you can have infinitive loop

Comment: True, code could be improved by making a fail safe with the array length. Will add it.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but I think I'll go with jerjer's solution. Unless you can tell me yours has something more or profounder to offer?

Comment: Mine is shorter and cleaner and more efficient?

Comment: @saratis Is it? Why would you think so? You keep on looping until there are no more entries, whereas the other solution "breaks" when the word is found. I'd argue that your solution is less efficient, to be honest. Cleaner is personal opinion, and it isn't shorter.